# Does every rails app have a default application.html.erb created in their layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view

I just had a general doubt which I wanted to clear wrt Rails. I am currently working on Rails 2.0.2 for project specific purposes and I had a doubt especially related to this version of Rails.

I did a basic scaffold in my rails app on "posts".. something like `ruby script/generate scaffold posts` . This created a posts.html.erb file for me in my app/views/layouts .. I have seen in many blogs/screen casts they say when we add Javascript(JS) files like for e.g. those implementing jquery etc. we need to make include the necessary files in our `"application.html.erb"`files.. Now since I don't have anything exactly coined as such in my app.. does Rails by default take my `posts.html.erb` in my layouts as the equivalent `application.html.erb`..?

Or is that I need to explicitly create application.html.erb in my rails app?

My main concern behind this question is that would JS files be included in case if I have something like `posts.html.erb` or is that.. it should be done only in the `application.html.erb`..

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does Rails by default take my posts.html.erb in my layouts as the equivalent application.html.erb..?

Yes. For the PostsController it will (by convention) take `layouts/posts.html.erb` as the overall layout template.

If you remove this file it will fall back to the `layouts/application.html.erb` layout.

> My main concern behind this question is that would JS files be included in case if I have something like posts.html.erb or is that.. it should be done only in the application.html.erb..

You would have to include all necessary JS/CSS in each layout, as there is no layout inheritance.

If you want multiple layouts you can refactor out sections into partials (eg: for the `<head>` bit).

Comment: - if there is no layout inheritance then how do you think jquery.js n other JS files are passed to different view(.html.erb files and .js.erb files) to get jquery related functions like those with AJAX running..? Also from your answer it seems like including all js files n stylesheet files in application.html.erb would make more sense as it adheres to DRY principle in Rails providing all a global scope of access to various controllers and their related views..Kindly correct me if I am wrong on this..

Comment: To start with, read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html. It will help you get a better idea of how layouts work.

Comment: There is no layout inheritance in the sense that if you have two different layouts, you can't inherit one from the other. Note the difference between **layouts** and **views** here. Layouts are an overall page template that contain (one or more) `yield` statements within it, where Rails render a view (so at runtime Rails combines the view with the selected layout and renders the page).

Answer (score 1):

For a `PostsController`, Rails will first look for an `app/views/layouts/posts.html.erb` file. Only if it doesn't find this controller-specific layout will it then fall back to `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

an app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file should have been generated for you when you did "rails new ProjectName"

make sure you have one... it controls the general layout of your web-site.

Comment: -It didn't get created for me..in my case that could be so as I was using Rails 2.0.2 ..Thanks for your answer..